# Is there a more efficient way to fliter old records out of c# dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary list with datetime as the key. That datetime is not related to the current time.

Whenever a new record gets added to the list, I also want to remove any records older than 24 hours from the newest datetime in the list, so I run something like this:

```
records = records.Where(x => x.Key > theDate).ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Value);
```

However, as there are tens of thousands of records, running this on every new record is costly.

Is there a more efficient way to filter out/remove older records than the way I am doing it above.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but perhaps [SortedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.1) may be more efficient than regular `Dictionary` for filtering on keys

Comment: Due to the nature of OP's use case the red-black tree behind the SortedDictionary will have to be rebalanced very often. OP should compare the performance of the SortedDictionary and dictionary ring for their use case.

Comment: What is the use case for the dictionary?, it seems to be the wrong tool for the job.. what problem are you trying to solve with it?

Comment: It seems like overkill to purge the dictionary of old elements each and every time you add a new one. What's the driver behind doing so?

Comment: My suggestion is not to remove them at _add_ time, but at _read_ time. So you build a method that returns all of the data and if it ever sees old data it fails to return it (and removes it at the same time).

Answer (score 2):

Partition the data into multiple dictionaries, each corresponding to a an hour (or other suitable granularity based on profiling). You can then keep a ring buffer of 25 dictionaries to cover the last 24 hours, and either not return anything for lookups more than 24 hours ago, or only have to filter a fraction of your keys, depending on exact requirements.